# How to downgrade "compileSdkVersion" in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

Currently I am using the API Level 23 for the "compileSdkVersion", but I want to downgrade it to 17. So how to do that? After changing the value, I am getting following errors. Following is my build.gradle file. The errors I am getting shows that I've to change some styles and themes of the app. As a beginner, I don't know how to deal with styles and themes according to API Levels. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you in advance!

build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 17
buildToolsVersion "19.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "kk.kk.ver1"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 17
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
}
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Errors:

[image]

Comment: "but I want to downgrade it to 17" -- why?

Comment: Because I want to run my app on Android version 4.2.2, which is API Level 17.

Comment: You can run it on API level 17, even if you're targeting something higher. Android is backwards compatible in that way.

Comment: That has nothing to do with your `compileSdkVersion`. Your `minSdkVersion` controls how old of an Android device you will support, and you already have that set to 14. Leave your `compileSdkVersion` alone.

Comment: So according to you guys, is my code perfect?

Comment: keep your compileSdkVersion at 23, not 17. Your app will still run fine if you're compiling over 17. Based on that configuration your app will run on devices running Ice Cream Sandwich (api 14) **through** Marshmallow (api 23). The error you posted is referencing something else entirely.

Comment: lol no. no one said your code is perfect, we said that you shouldn't touch compileSdkVersion, instead, change minSdkVersion

Comment: Thank you so much guys, I changed the compileSdkVersion to API Level 23 and it worked. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

open build.gradle(Module App) file and change the compile sdk version. After that make a resync